# C# -delegate array - how to add tostring methods

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, tostring

Is it possible to add ToString methods to an array of delegates??  If so how?? here is the code I have written:

```
public delegate string Task();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList studentArray = new ArrayList();
        Course italianCook = new ItalianCookCourse { Teacher = "Ben Hodd" };
        Course seafoodCook = new SeafoodCookCourse { Teacher = "Harry Cotter"};
        Course sewingCourse = new SewingCourse
        {
            Teacher = "Margaret Mair",
            ChargePerStudent = scFee,
            CostPerStudent = 100.00m,
        };
        Course creativeWrite = new CreativeWritCourse { Teacher = "Mary Smith };
        Course businessWrite = new BusinessWritCourse { Teacher = "Mary Smith" };
        Task[] tasks = new Task(italianCook.ToString, seafoodCook.ToString, sewingCourse.ToString);
```

The error message is "string Class.ToString()" - "Method name expected"

As the tostring method handle as a string, is it possible to add it to delagate??

Comment: Are those two methods you're trying to pass at the same time? That's not quite how you instantiate a single Task object or add items to a Task[] array...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you fixed up the syntax, the solution would be to remove the ()'s from the end of the ToString's. To create a delegate based on a method, you only need to give its name.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[] { Class1.ToString, Class2.ToString }
```

Note that the above code **does not actually compile.** ToString() is not a static method, so you need to pass in an object reference along with the function name:

```
object o = new object();
Task[] tasks = new Task[] { o.ToString };
```

Comment: Thanks - I did try that and got another message "(paramater) Course italianCook" "Method name expected"....??

Comment: Hi - italianCook is an instance of class Course and an object - as above it still does not work??

Comment: What does your code look like now? As BoltClock mentioned, your current syntax is incorrect.